# How to replace NULL to 0 in pivot table output values

Tags: sql-server-2014

i have a pivot table that display student absence, there is not problem in executing and the result of the pivot but if there is no value it display null, i want to display 0 not a null. i googled and found some ways i try use them but i can't do it. can anyone tell me please?
this my pivot table code:

`create proc [dbo].[get_st_abs_by_stage]
 @Stage_ID smallint
 as
     CREATE TABLE #SummaryTable
    (
      SName nvarchar(50),
      CName nvarchar(50),
      Stage_ID SmallInt,
      Sum_Abs SmallInt
     )
    delete from #SummaryTable
    INSERT INTO #SummaryTable(SName, CName, Stage_ID, Sum_Abs)
    SELECT Student_tbl.SName,Courses_tbl.CName,Stages_tbl.Stage_ID,Sum_Abs   from Absence_Summary_tbl
    inner join Student_tbl on Student_tbl.S_ID = Absence_Summary_tbl.S_ID
    inner join Stages_tbl on Stages_tbl.Stage_ID = Student_tbl.Stage_ID
    inner join Courses_tbl on Courses_tbl.C_ID = Absence_Summary_tbl.C_ID
    where Stages_tbl.Stage_ID = @Stage_ID;
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(CName) 
                    from #SummaryTable
                    where Stage_ID = @Stage_ID
                    group by CName
                    order by CName
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') ,1,1,'')
set @query = 'SELECT SName,' + @cols + ' from 
             (
                select SName, CName, Sum_Abs
                from #SummaryTable
             ) x
            pivot 
             (
                sum(Sum_Abs)
                for CName in (' + @cols + ')
             ) p '
execute(@query);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate another variable with isnull for cols. Something like this

```
select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(CName) 
                    from #SummaryTable
                    where Stage_ID = @Stage_ID
                    group by CName
                    order by CName
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') ,1,1,'')
select @isnull_cols = STUFF((SELECT ', isnull(' + QUOTENAME(CName) + ', 0) as ' + QUOTENAME(CName)
                    from #SummaryTable
                    where Stage_ID = @Stage_ID
                    group by CName
                    order by CName
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') ,1,1,'')
set @query = 'SELECT SName,' + @isnull_cols + ' from 
             (
                select SName, CName, Sum_Abs
                from #SummaryTable
             ) x
            pivot 
             (
                sum(Sum_Abs)
                for CName in (' + @cols + ')
             ) p '
execute(@query);
```